# how to scan ble device based on the mac address stored in database using python

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi3

I am using for loop to get the mac address from database but the loop printed the ble mac address 17 times. I tried using if else to compare the mac address with the mac address stored in database but the output scan nothing. Is there any other way to filter out other ble mac address?

```
import os
import sys
import struct
import bluetooth._bluetooth as bluez
import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","DB_USER","DB_PASSWORD","DB_NAME" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM Mac_address"

cursor.execute(sql)

# Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
    NAME = row[0]    
    mac_address = row[1]
    time = row[2]


LE_META_EVENT = 0x3e
LE_PUBLIC_ADDRESS=0x00
LE_RANDOM_ADDRESS=0x01
LE_SET_SCAN_PARAMETERS_CP_SIZE=7
OGF_LE_CTL=0x08
OCF_LE_SET_SCAN_PARAMETERS=0x000B
OCF_LE_SET_SCAN_ENABLE=0x000C
OCF_LE_CREATE_CONN=0x000D

LE_ROLE_MASTER = 0x00
LE_ROLE_SLAVE = 0x01

# these are actually subevents of LE_META_EVENT
EVT_LE_CONN_COMPLETE=0x01
EVT_LE_ADVERTISING_REPORT=0x02
EVT_LE_CONN_UPDATE_COMPLETE=0x03
EVT_LE_READ_REMOTE_USED_FEATURES_COMPLETE=0x04

# Advertisment event types
ADV_IND=0x00
ADV_DIRECT_IND=0x01
ADV_SCAN_IND=0x02
ADV_NONCONN_IND=0x03
ADV_SCAN_RSP=0x04


def returnnumberpacket(pkt):
myInteger = 0
multiple = 256
for c in pkt:
    myInteger +=  struct.unpack("B",c)[0] * multiple
    multiple = 1
return myInteger 

def returnstringpacket(pkt):
    myString = "";
for c in pkt:
    myString +=  "%02x" %struct.unpack("B",c)[0]
return myString 

def printpacket(pkt):
    for c in pkt:
       sys.stdout.write("%02x " % struct.unpack("B",c)[0])

def get_packed_bdaddr(bdaddr_string):
    packable_addr = []
    addr = bdaddr_string.split(':')
    addr.reverse()
    for b in addr: 
       packable_addr.append(int(b, 16))
       return struct.pack("<BBBBBB", *packable_addr)

def packed_bdaddr_to_string(bdaddr_packed):
    return ':'.join('%02x'%i for i in struct.unpack("<BBBBBB", bdaddr_packed[::-1]))

def hci_enable_le_scan(sock):
    hci_toggle_le_scan(sock, 0x01)

def hci_disable_le_scan(sock):
    hci_toggle_le_scan(sock, 0x00)

def hci_toggle_le_scan(sock, enable)

cmd_pkt = struct.pack("<BB", enable, 0x00)
bluez.hci_send_cmd(sock, OGF_LE_CTL, OCF_LE_SET_SCAN_ENABLE, cmd_pkt)


def hci_le_set_scan_parameters(sock):
    old_filter = sock.getsockopt( bluez.SOL_HCI, bluez.HCI_FILTER, 14)

    SCAN_RANDOM = 0x01
    OWN_TYPE = SCAN_RANDOM
    SCAN_TYPE = 0x01



def parse_events(sock, loop_count=100):
    old_filter = sock.getsockopt( bluez.SOL_HCI, bluez.HCI_FILTER, 14)

    # perform a device inquiry on bluetooth device #0
    # The inquiry should last 8 * 1.28 = 10.24 seconds
    # before the inquiry is performed, bluez should flush its cache of
    # previously discovered devices
    flt = bluez.hci_filter_new()
    bluez.hci_filter_all_events(flt)
    bluez.hci_filter_set_ptype(flt, bluez.HCI_EVENT_PKT)
    sock.setsockopt( bluez.SOL_HCI, bluez.HCI_FILTER, flt )
    done = False
    results = []
    myFullList = []
    for i in range(0, loop_count):
       pkt = sock.recv(255)
       ptype, event, plen = struct.unpack("BBB", pkt[:3])
       #print "--------------" 
       if event == bluez.EVT_INQUIRY_RESULT_WITH_RSSI:
            i =0
       elif event == bluez.EVT_NUM_COMP_PKTS:
            i =0 
       elif event == bluez.EVT_DISCONN_COMPLETE:
            i =0 
       elif event == LE_META_EVENT:
            subevent, = struct.unpack("B", pkt[3])
            pkt = pkt[4:]
            if subevent == EVT_LE_CONN_COMPLETE:
               le_handle_connection_complete(pkt)
            elif subevent == EVT_LE_ADVERTISING_REPORT:
               #print "advertising report"
               num_reports = struct.unpack("B", pkt[0])[0]
               report_pkt_offset = 0
               for i in range(0, num_reports):
                   Mac = packed_bdaddr_to_string(pkt[report_pkt_offset + 3:report_pkt_offset + 9])
                   for Mac in row[1]:
                      print "-------------"
                      #print "\tfullpacket: ", printpacket(pkt)
                      print "\tMAC address: ", row[1]                         # commented out - don't know what this byte is.  It's NOT TXPower
                      txpower, = struct.unpack("b", pkt[report_pkt_offset -2])
                      print "\t(Unknown):", txpower

                      rssi, = struct.unpack("b", pkt[report_pkt_offset -1])
                      print "\tRSSI:", rssi
                      break
        # build the return string
                Adstring = packed_bdaddr_to_string(pkt[report_pkt_offset + 3:report_pkt_offset + 9])
        Adstring += ","
        Adstring += returnstringpacket(pkt[report_pkt_offset -22: report_pkt_offset - 6]) 
        Adstring += ","
        Adstring += "%i" % returnnumberpacket(pkt[report_pkt_offset -6: report_pkt_offset - 4]) 
        Adstring += ","
        Adstring += "%i" % returnnumberpacket(pkt[report_pkt_offset -4: report_pkt_offset - 2]) 
        Adstring += ","
        Adstring += "%i" % struct.unpack("b", pkt[report_pkt_offset -2])
        Adstring += ","
        Adstring += "%i" % struct.unpack("b", pkt[report_pkt_offset -1])

        #print "\tAdstring=", Adstring
        myFullList.append(Adstring)
            done = True
sock.setsockopt( bluez.SOL_HCI, bluez.HCI_FILTER, old_filter )
return myFullList
db.close()
```

The above is save as blescan.py. I run this file below to do a ble scan.

```
import blescan 
import sys 


import bluetooth._bluetooth as bluez 

dev_id = 0 
try: 
   sock = bluez.hci_open_dev(dev_id) 
   print "ble thread started" 


except: 
   print "error accessing bluetooth device..." 
   sys.exit(1) 


blescan.hci_le_set_scan_parameters(sock) 
blescan.hci_enable_le_scan(sock) 


while True: 
  returnedList = blescan.parse_events(sock, 10) 
  print "----------"
```

Comment: You have a `while True` without `break`. It will run forever and block.

Comment: Thank but how do I scan the ble Mac address that I stored inside the database to monitor it RSSI value.

Comment: You re not using any threads as far as  I see. So, how it the data updated while the thread is blocked by the loop?

Comment: The Mac in row[1] loop dosen't make any difference but the print row[1] mac address take over the received mac address.

Comment: You did not answer the question I gave. Your code does not even show where `row` comes from. But it does not matter matter, since you never going to leave the while loop again.

Comment: Thank for helping me. I guess I have solved this question.